# Importing data names without ''

Tags: r, import

I am currently reading data using read_excel('PATH.xlsx',sheet=1, skip=1,col_names=T) and for some reason some columns add ' ' to the names i.e *df1$`observation'*

Is there a way to remove these quotations during the importing process? I am currently renaming all the columns with mutate but figured I would look for an alternative since it keeps on ocurring.
Thanks!

Comment: do you have spaces in column names? Can you add a small example?

Comment: @RonakShah Makes total sense, the fields have spaces in them. Thanks for that! Is there a way to add a parameter to turn spaces into _ or something similar to avoid the quotation marks or is my mutating the names the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column names with spaces are not syntactically valid. A simple way to turn them into valid names would be to use `make.names` which turn the spaces into `"."`

```
df <- data.frame('A spaced column' = 1:3, 'Another column' = 4:6, check.names = FALSE)
names(df) <- make.names(names(df))

df
#  A.spaced.column Another.column
#1               1              4
#2               2              5
#3               3              6
```

If you want a custom way to replace the names we can use `gsub`.

```
names(df) <- gsub(' ', '_', names(df))
```